# Creation of global variables?

Tags: python, variables, global

For the code below I have some doubt.

```
def spam():
    global eggs
    eggs = 'spam'
eggs ='global'
spam()
print(eggs)
```

The result is `spam`. 
My questions are as follows:
Do we have two  global variables in that code?
Why it executes only `eggs = 'spam'` but not `eggs = 'global'`?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You only have one global variable, named `eggs` in that code. You assign a value to it twice, first with the string 'global' and again with the string 'spam' in the function.

I think the term `global` is a bit of a misnomer in Python. Names are only global to the module, so if you tried to access `eggs` from another module, it would not exist unless you imported it.

Comment: "it would not exist unless you imported it" - and even then, if you used a `from` import, you'd be working with your own new variable global to only your module, and assignments to one variable wouldn't affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

It does execute `eggs = 'global'`, its value gets changed again by `eggs = 'spam'`.

Your spam function accesses the global scope and changes `eggs` to `'spam'`.

Answer (score 0):

The result is spam because you ran the procedure after you assigned 'global' to eggs. The procedure assigns 'spam' to eggs.